# How to add image to header?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm trying to add an image to the header of my VBA generated Word document.

```
Sub CreateBasicWordReport()
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application

    Set wdApp = New Word.Application

    With wdApp
        .Visible = True
        .Activate

        .Documents.Add
        With .Selection
            .HeaderFooter.Shapes.AddPicture _
             "C:\Users\[user_name]\Desktop\AHA Logo 2016.pdf", True, _
             False, 100, 75, -1, -1, True
```

The code runs until I get to the last line. Then I get

> Runtime error 91:
>   Object variable or With block variable not set

Comment: And what is the text of the error? No one memorizes the numbers...

Comment: "Object variable or With block variable not set"

Answer (score 2):

Although Intellisense offers the objects used in the line of code causing the problem, it doesn't really work. That's because a Header (or Footer) is specific to a document `Section`. Every document has one section by default. Since the code is creating a new document from the default template, it will have one section.

Then, each section has three possible header types. There can be one for the first page of the section, another for even pages (if the odd/even option is activated) and then there's the "primary" header/footer, which is what is generated by default in this scenario.

Therefore, in order to address a header or footer, it's necessary to specify the section and the type of header/footer. The following adds the Shape to the default first section, primary header:

```
Sub CreateBasicWordReport()
    Dim wdApp As Word.Application
    Dim doc as Word.Document

    Set wdApp = New Word.Application

    With wdApp
        .Visible = True
        .Activate

        Set doc = .Documents.Add
        With doc
           .Sections(1).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Shapes.AddPicture _
             "C:\Users\[user_name]\Desktop\AHA Logo 2016.pdf", True, _
             False, 100, 75, -1, -1, True
```

Comment: Now the error is, "Requested object is no available"

Comment: AFAIK pdf is not a supported picture type.

Comment: Yes file path was corrected and it didn't work with JPG and PNG files either

Comment: I'm assuming the error is still on the `AddPicture` line and not elsewhere? Then the problem comes in narrowing down what object is meant. Try breaking the code down into multiple lines in order to isolate the problem. Example: `Dim sec as Word.Section : Set sec = .Sections(1) : Dim hdr as Word.HeaderFooter : Set hdr = sec.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)` and so on.